# Android: EditText value equals null

Tags: android

I am currently making a converter tool as a project. Of course when the value in a editText box equal nothing the app will crash if i tried to do a calculation with it.

So i have wrote the routine below, the code fixes the problem (Setting editText hint as "Enter Value". The problem is that now my calculation code doesn't run. How can i fix this problem?

```
           if (e1 != null ){

                e1.setHint("Enter Value");

                if (e2 != null){
                    e2.setHint("Enter Value");
                }
                if (e3 != null){
                    e3.setHint("Enter Value");

                }
                if (e4 != null){
                    e4.setHint("Enter Value");

                }
                if (e5 != null){
                    e5.setHint("Enter Value");

                }
                if (e7 != null){
                    e7.setHint("Enter Value");

                }
            }else{

                //code runs
```

Merry Christmas and thank you for your help,

Mario.

- Sorry if my English is bad

Comment: Wait, what does setting a hint fix, exactly?

Comment: Is e1-e5 your `EditText`
?

Comment: In this example, the code would only run when e1 == null, which I'm assuming is not the goal.

Comment: Where does `e1` get set?

Comment: The hint indicates that a value is need in the box.

Comment: Yes e1 - 5 is Edit Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want check Edittext have some 'text' or not you can use these

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(e1.getText())){
      // edittext1 not empty
}else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(e2.getText())){
      //  edittext2 not empty
}else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(e3.getText())){
      //  edittext3 not empty
}
```

Comment: That code works great thank you, How could i do this for all the other editTexts?

Comment: check my updated code, you can do something like that, attention for `!`

Answer (score 1):

With `if (e1 != null )` you are checking if EditText is null. if you want to check if there is text inside e1, you have to use `if (!e1.getText().toString().equals(""))`.
getText() method never returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Have a class for validation as Validation.java

```
public class Validation  {
    public boolean Is_Empty(EditText edt) {
            if (edt.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                edt.requestFocus();
                // Following code will show 'FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY' popup to the user
                edt.setError(Html
                        .fromHtml("<font color='black'>FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY</font>"));
            }else{
                edt.setError(null);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            }
            }
```

And in your activity check it as follow :

```
Validation valid=new Validation();

            if(!valid.Is_Empty(edt))
            {   
             // Edit Text is not empty
}
```